# MySQL meltdown; 1045

Tags: mysql, rubygems, homebrew

It is my first day trying to create a MySQL server on my Mountain Lion 64x Mac. I have installed MySQL 5.6.12 by downloading it from MySQL Dev.

The problem is, *I cannot turn mySQL off from system preferences*. I installed the MySQL2 Ruby Gem. When I start Rails and try to access at localhost:3000, I get:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

In short, I must have done something wrong. I installed MySQL using homebrew as well as using the dev DMG installer. Did that break it?

**Update:**

Still having issues. I unistalled mysql using this tutorial: http://maison.io/blog/removing-mysql-osx

Then I unistalled using homebrew
Then I tried gem check mysql2
Got this error:

```
    mysql2-0.3.11.gem has 8 problems
    ext/mysql2/.RUBYARCHDIR.time:
    Extra file
    ext/mysql2/Makefile:
    Extra file
    ext/mysql2/client.o:
    Extra file
    ext/mysql2/mkmf.log:
    Extra file
    ext/mysql2/mysql2.bundle:
    Extra file
    ext/mysql2/mysql2_ext.o:
    Extra file
    ext/mysql2/result.o:
    Extra file
    lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle:
    Extra file
```

Ok Fine. Amended database.yml. Now I need to create a new database. I'm using
        rake create:db

The Issue:

```
    Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8",         
    "database"=>"simple_cms_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=<password>, 
    "socket"=>"/tmp/mysql.sock"}
```

Another error:

Tried running:

```
    mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local
    FATAL ERROR: Could not find my-default.cnf
```

I am totally at a loss. Thoughts?

Comment: I don’t know about Mac, but can you use `mysqladmin -u root -p pass` in your terminal?

Comment: Yeah I can access MySQL that way. Doesn't solve the Rails session issue, though, is my problem.

Comment: Change your password there, and use that password.

Comment: I ended up with some thing like that. Ended up uninstalling both and then using brew's version. Could have used the dmg, but things get all crossed up if you do both

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Is there a best practice for making the uninstalls?

Comment: Well you've uninstalled both, I see no mention of reinstalling one of them. I think I had to manually delete a couple of things, also had to reboot, but that might have been my lack of Mac knowledge.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I am still trying. It's such hell. I reinstalled using the DMG file. Now the preferences pane will not start the database. Terminal does not respond to commands for mysql.

Comment: I used Brew, afraid I'm a bit intermediate on nix and a complete novice on MAC, but after a bit of pursing about I did get it to work.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I also got it to work. had to execute many lines and make many uninstalls and installs, form links, change permissions. What kind of crap is this!

Comment: The sort of crap you get when you install the same application twice. Still like me, I bet you won't do it again. :p